# How to remove Phonegap access origin whitelist wildcard

Tags: cordova

I'm using Phonegap (version 3.3.0-0.17.1) and according to the docs, it has `<access origin="*" />` by default.  This definitely appears to be the case in the new project I created.  In my `ProjectFolder/www/config.xml` file, it had that same entry.  I removed that line, performed a build, but the underlying config.xml files for each platform still have that line.  If I manually remove the line from the platform-specific config files, and perform a build, that line comes back.  How do I actually remove that line?  It is, by default, allowing cross domain Ajax requests anywhere... seems like an odd default to me.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, my build process for phonegap platform works via [gruntjs plugin](https://github.com/logankoester/grunt-phonegap). Each time it clears destination folder, creates phonegap project in this folder, copies to www folder my sources and compiled config.xml, adds specified plugins and performs build of native application.

This is my project structure:

```
/root
---/bower_components/
---/node_modules/
---/src/
---/out/
------/phonegap
---/index.html
---/Gruntfile.js
---/package.json
---/bower.json
---/config.tpl.xml
---/.jshintrc
```

This is how my phonegap task configuration look like:

```
      phonegap : {
         config : {
            root : './src',
            config : {
               template : './config.tpl.xml',
               data: {
                  id: pkg.id,
                  version: pkg.version,
                  name: pkg.name,
                  author : pkg.author
               }
            },
            path : 'out/phonegap',
            plugins : [
               // PHONEGAP OFFICIAL PLUGINS
               'org.apache.cordova.globalization',
               'org.apache.cordova.network-information',
               'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen',

               //THIRD-PARTY PLUGINS
               'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification'
            ],
            platforms : [
               'android'
            ],
            maxBuffer : 200, // You may need to raise this for iOS.
            verbose : false,

            // Android-only integer version to increase with each release.
            // See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html
            versionCode : function() {
               return 1;
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: But if you remove the `<access origin="*" />` from the config.xml file, and perform a build, is it _actually_ gone from the config file in each platform's directory?

Comment: @chinabuffet config.xml is getting created each time when build is launched. Only grunt template exits in sources.